# unable to use spring component-scan feature in JBoss 5.1.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss5.x

I am facing challenge in using Spring 3.0 component-scan feature with JBoss 5.1.2. i am not able to use @Autowired feature. Below are the Code which i configured.

My Web.xml

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

applicationContext.xml consist of the below line i have imported the beans,context xsd in file. applicationContext-hibernate.xml file contains Hibernate configuration Details.

```
    <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.mycom.cmc" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-hibernate.xml" />
```

Below is the class which i using for doing DAO operation.

```
@Repository("batchProcessingTxDAO")
 public class BatchProcessingTxDAOImpl extends HibernateRepository implements
    BatchProcessingTxDAO {

private static final Logger log = Logger
        .getLogger(BatchProcessingTxDAOImpl.class);

@Override
public void saveBatchProcessingTx(BatchProcessingTx batchProcessingTx) {

    try {
        if (batchProcessingTx != null) {
            log.info(String
                    .format("saving BatchProcessingTx details for batchProcessingTxId :: %s",
                            batchProcessingTx.getBatchProcessingTxId()));
            hibernateTemplate.save(batchProcessingTx);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(String
                .format("Exception occured while saving the BatchProcessingTx caused by :: %s",
                        e));

    }
    log.info(String
            .format("Sucessfully saved BatchProcessingTx details for batchProcessingTxId ::%s",
                    batchProcessingTx.getBatchProcessingTxId()));

}

@Override
public BatchProcessingTx getBatchProcessingTxByBatchProcessingTxId(
        BigDecimal batchProcessingTxId) {
    System.out.println("called Sucessfully 1212121111111111111111111");
    BatchProcessingTx batchProcessingTx = null;
   /*
    if (batchProcessingTxId != null) {
        log.info(String.format(
                "BatchProcessingTx details for batchProcessingTxId :: %s",
                batchProcessingTxId));
        batchProcessingTx = hibernateTemplate.get(BatchProcessingTx.class,
                batchProcessingTxId);
    }
     */
    return batchProcessingTx;

}
```

}

```
public abstract class HibernateRepository {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Required
@Autowired(required =true)
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
public void setSessionFactory(final SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

}

When i deploy the application on the JBoss Container i can see the .hbm files and JNDI connection is happening properly. but i can not see the class is getting scanned in server log JBoss Container.

```
19:49:54,958 INFO  [[/CMC]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:49:55,598 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.BatchProcessingTx -> BATCH_PROCESSING_TX
19:49:55,598 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.BrandMapping -> BRAND_MAPPING
19:49:55,614 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ClientAccessRule -> CLIENT_ACCESS_RULE
19:49:55,614 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ContractInfo -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,630 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ExceptionInfo -> EXCEPTION_INFO
19:49:55,630 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.PdfDocumentMapping -> PDF_DOCUMENT_MAPPING
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ReferenceInfo -> REFERENCE_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping class: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.WebServiceTx -> WEB_SERVICE_TX
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ContractInfo.batchProcessingTxes -> BATCH_PROCESSING_TX
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ContractInfo.exceptionInfos -> EXCEPTION_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.PdfDocumentMapping.contractInfosForFairUsePolicyId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.PdfDocumentMapping.contractInfosForTermsOfServiceId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.PdfDocumentMapping.contractInfosForPrivacyPolicyId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.PdfDocumentMapping.contractInfosForAddedClausesId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ReferenceInfo.contractInfosForContractReasonId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ReferenceInfo.contractInfosForContractTypeId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ReferenceInfo.contractInfosForContractMediaId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.ReferenceInfo.contractInfosForContractDistributionTypeId -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,645 INFO  [HbmBinder] Mapping collection: com.myapp.cmc.domain.model.WebServiceTx.contractInfos -> CONTRACT_INFO
19:49:55,661 INFO  [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] RDBMS: Oracle, version: Oracle Database 10g     Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: Oracle JDBC driver, version: 10.1.0.4.0
19:49:55,661 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
19:49:55,661 INFO  [JdbcSupportLoader] Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
19:49:55,661 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
19:49:55,661 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch size: 15
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Scrollable result sets: enabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Connection release mode: auto
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default batch fetch size: 1
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Generate SQL with comments: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
19:49:55,661 INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query language substitutions: {}
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Statistics: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default entity-mode: pojo
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Named query checking : enabled
19:49:55,661 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] building session factory
19:49:55,723 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

when i try save the object i am getting NullPointerException. i think the Spring component scan feature is not working. Due to that i am unable to get hibernateTemplate instance. And i don't see any scanning for the class in the Log file of JBoss server log. Please tell me what i missed it. or is it issue with JBoss 5.1.2 with Spring 3.0.

Comment: Can you post the code where and how you are using the service... Is it working in a test case? And please post the actual stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace what i given is the actual stack trace when the application get deployed successfully on the server. I don't have Junit testcase for this code. I am directly calling it from the Service layer class. If i use the @Autowired then the object what i am getting the null.

Comment: There is no stacktrace in your post and please show us the code where and how you call this service...

Comment: Thanks Deinum for quick response.Please find the stack trace below. 19:49:54,958 INFO  [[/CMC]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19:49:55,661 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Transaction strategy: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringTransactionFactory
19:49:55,661 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
19:49:55,723 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured.

Comment: I will post the code for service layer for accessing DAO layer.But what i except is there should be a statement which says that [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1062 ms. But it is not appering the log. when the application intialized.

Answer (score 0):

annotate HibernateRepository class with @Component or with @Repository (preferred). It should work.

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. for testing purpose when i called the DAOImpl class i was NullPointerException.

Comment: "19:49:55,723 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured"  -- from above log I guess JNDI datasource might not have configured properly. Please check.

Comment: Guys, I did some changes in Jboss-log4j.xml file. I change the spring logging level to DEBUG and then i saw that classpath scanning related logs. But still i am unable to get the object created by Container. Still unable to get the null object from container.

Comment: Hi All, I am able to resolve the issue. The issue was the way of exposing the webservices. My WebServices was JAX-WS and it's handling is done with the web container. And another is Spring Container also running. so i need someone who can make a communication between these two container. For resolving this issue spring has provided a class SpringBeanAutoWiringSupport which can inject the dependency inside the class. So i need the to extend the class with SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.